# Js char array treats string integers as integers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have char array:

```
a = [ 'm', 'a', 'q', '0', '2', 'o' ]
```

when I try an extend the array for any element:

```
a[a['0']] = something;
```

it treats '0' as the index 0

Why does this happen?

---EDIT---

What I wish to do is say a[a[3]] = something so that when I evaluate a['0'] it returns 'something';

Comment: An array is supposed to be accessed by index. Aren't you confusing arrays and objects ?

Comment: `[]` creates an array whose indices are integers. If you pass in a string as the index, javascript attempts to parse the string to an integer. `'0'` simply becomes `0`. I think what you may be thinking of is an *object* which would treat `a[0]` and `a['0']` differently.

Comment: I incorrectly flagged your comment. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

> It treats '0' as the index 0

Because that's what the `[]` notation means: Look up or assign to the property in the object with that key. Normal arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects with some special behavior; the syntax isn't specific to arrays, it's object-wide.

> And how do overcome this?

and in your edit:

> What I wish to do is say `a[a[3]] = something` so that when I evaluate `a['0']` it returns 'something';

That would work:

```
a[a[3]] = 'something';
console.log(a['0']); // something
```

```js
var a = [ 'm', 'a', 'q', '0', '2', 'o' ]
var something = "foo";

a[a[3]] = 'something';
snippet.log(a['0']); // something
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Since it remains unclear what you're trying to do, all I can do is tell you what your code is doing:

```
a[a['0']] = something
```

is

```
var x = a['0'];
a[x] = something
```

...which, with your array is

```
var x = 'm'; // Because a['0'] has the value 'm' in it
a['m'] = something
```

...which puts an `m` property on the array object:

```js
var a = [ 'm', 'a', 'q', '0', '2', 'o' ]
var something = "foo";

a[a['0']] = something;
snippet.log(a.m);    // "foo" -- we're accessing the `m` property of the object
snippet.log(a['m']); // also "foo", you can use either dot notation or brackets notation
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone else.  Arrays in javascript don't behave as standard arrays.  However, if I were to guess based upon your code example that you might be trying to update an object within and array.  If that is the case, then you could do the following:

```
a[a.indexOf('0')] = something;
```